# Watch a property that can be undefined / default value for nested watch property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a Vue2 project and I have a problem with a property that I want to watch.
This is how it looks like :

```js
watch: {
  'car.wheels': function(){
      ...
  }
```

sometimes, wheels is `undefined`. Is there a way to set a default value ?
I tried to do it by using a computed :

```js
computed: {
  wheels(){
     return car.wheels ? car.wheels : somethingElse
  }
},
watch: {
   wheels: function(){
      ...
   }
}
```

This solution doesn't always works. Indeed, when the computed is updated, the watcher isn't (and it's still watching somethingElse even if there is a value in car.wheels)
Hope it was clear !

PS : watching `car` instead of `wheels` isn't an option, as car is updated really often and there is a bunch of processing inside of the watcher)

PS 2 : car is a store data that I update in another component

Comment: is `car` a prop? can you include more code

Comment: Car is a store data

Comment: What do you need ? I can't copy paste my whole code, it's a big project

Comment: [mcve] would help

Comment: "This solution doesn't always works" - this part needs to be explained, as it's generally expected to work. "sometimes, wheels is undefined" - what is the problem with this?

Comment: It works when i reload, because the watcher is reseted. But if I don't relaod, it always watch somethingElse

Comment: It's unclear what's the problem with default value, you could specify it in a place where car.wheels is consumed, which seems to be a watcher. This depends on your case, generally there's no such problem. That a computed doesn't work as intended suggests like car.wheels is just not reactive. Please, provide a way to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a created/mounted lifecycle hook, to set the default value there first, and then if the value changes, it the watcher will react.

Comment: It seems like a good idea. I hoped that there was a solution directly in watcher parameter but if there isn't any, I will do that (I'll just wait a little bit to see if someone has another idea before validating your answer)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can set the default value of `wheel` when updating car data in VueStore.

Btw, It would be better to use `{ deep: true }` property to watch data from `computed` in your code example.